# expansion taylor series; mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series at $x=0$ for $\frac{1}{x-1} = -1 - x - x^2 - x^3 - \cdots$

The Taylor series at $x=0$ for $\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{12}-\frac{x^3}{720}+\cdots$

However, when substituting the Taylor series at $x=0$ for $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$ in the first result, there clearly doesn't appear any $\frac{1}{x}$.

Where is the mistake, as I think it's perfectly fine to substitute $e^x$ as the expansion is done around $0.$

Comment: The second function is not defined at $x=0$, and you obtain  a *Laurent's expansion* near $0$, not a *Taylor's series*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is basically as follows:

> You substitute the Taylor series for $e^x$ (around $0$) to $x$. That would be totally fine... **if** you indeed had $e^x \to 0$ when $x\to 0$.

But this is **not** the case. You are basically replacing the approximation of $e^x$ around $x=0$ (which goes to $1$) into something that is asking for a quantity going to $0$.